# Dict() index (from input int) printing associated value

Tags: python

I am trying to input multiple integers(if not in dict key(s), print error message), that should be in the keys of a dict(). The output should be the associated values for the input(keys).
Input used is: CSC120

In this case I am using "0,1,4" for the integer input.

I have worked with for loops and if clauses, but I am not getting the correct output. I am not seeing what I need to do to make it correct. Also have used the range within the for loop. Using the len(s) within the for loop returned the first 3 values "csc", while i need "CS2"

```
string1 = input("Enter a string:")
d = dict(enumerate(string1))

s = input("Enter a string(integer) separated by commas(in initial string1):")
s = s.split(',')
n = int(s[0])
value = d.values()
for i in d:
    if i == n:
        print(d[n])
```

Current results just print "C"
While desired results are: "CS2"

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code:

```
string1 = input("Enter a string:")
d = dict(enumerate(string1))

s = input("Enter a string(integer) separated by commas(in initial string1):")
s = s.split(',')
n = [int(i) for i in s]

for i in n:
    if i in d.keys():
        print(d[i], end="")
```

Comment: I have made adjustments on my end to have your code work. Thank you.